# Select a string using grep or awk

Tags: regex, awk, grep

i have the follow line and i need to get the variables like above

```
<port protocol="tcp" portid="9050"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="64"/><service name="tor-socks" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
```

this:

```
port=tcp
state=open
name=tor-socks
```

thank you

Comment: Do you want `port=tcp` or `protocol=tcp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To satisfy the requirement from your comment that `i need to get this in variable like $ echo "$protocol" and output is "tcp"`:

```
$ cat tst.sh
declare $(awk -v RS='[[:alpha:]]+="[^"]+"' 'RT{print RT}' "$1")
echo "$protocol"
echo "$state"
echo "$name"

$ ./tst.sh file
"tcp"
"open"
"tor-socks"
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT which I assume you have since you were happy with a GNU grep solution.

Answer (score 1):

*This will check for keywords like protocol,state,name and print till first space is seen. `tr` is used to remove double quotes.  Where $x is your string.*

```
echo $x  |grep -oP 'protocol=.*? |state=.*? |name=.*? ' |tr -d '"'
protocol=tcp
state=open
name=tor-socks
```

Approch-1:

```
protocol=$( echo $x  |grep -oP '(?<=protocol=").*?(?=")')
echo $protocol
tcp
```

Similarly :

```
protocol=$( echo $x  |grep -oP '(?<=protocol=").*?(?=")')
state=$(echo $x  |grep -oP '(?<=state=").*?(?=")')
name=$(echo $x  |grep -oP '(?<=name=").*?(?=")')
```

Approch-2:

or just do `eval` to assign values to respective variables. But I would avoid doing this, go with the first approach.

```
eval $(echo $x  |grep -oP 'protocol=.*? |state=.*? |name=.*? ')
echo $state
open
```

Comment: Thank you! and i have another ask. i need to get this in variable like $ echo "$protocol" and output is "tcp"

Comment: Thank you! first time i see a pratical use for eval :)

Comment: @JackMagor  you may want to accept the answer by ticking it if this helps

Comment: Don't do it. There's absolutely no reason to use eval for this and all the usual reasons not to. Also notice all the unquoted variables which are also a major red flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sed` to extract your data from the string and use `read` to assign individual string to variables :

```
 echo $line | sed 's/.*protocol="\([^"]*\)".*state="\([^"]*\)".*name="\([^"]*\)".*/\1 \2 \3/' | { read port state name; echo $port $state $name; }
```

Note that the variables `port`, `state`, `name` have their value inside the block enclosed by `{` and `}`.